# i have a input file to compare and check only one time execute and exit, if condition Hit only 1 times increment if range $1 (P to P) or N to N

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I want to if condition Hit only 1 times increment if range $1 (P to P) or N to N... Thanks.

input.txt

```
N;    577.5;    551.9;       0
P;    574.9;    556.9;     586.4
N;    561.95;   514.3;     504.01
P;    545;      520;       555.9
P;    559.05;   530.5;     555.9
P;    544.85;   522.25;    555.9
P;    543;      527;       555.9
P;    536.7;    517.7;     555.9
P;    540.55;   527.25;    555.9
P;    551.6;    525.2;     555.9
P;    542.1;    527;       555.9
P;    541;      521.2;     555.9
P;    541.9;    524.7;     555.9
P;    575.3;    532;       555.9
P;    572.8;    550;       555.9
P;    568.4;    541.45;    555.9
P;    574;      535;       555.9
P;    564;      548.4;     555.9
P;    572.05;   552.45;    555.9
P;    591.85;   565.15;    555.9
P;    602;      582.25;    555.9
P;    609;      575;       555.9
P;    611.95;   578.05;    555.9
P;    628;      604.9;     555.9
P;    611;      581;       555.9
N;    582.8;    565.2;     553.9
N;    581.5;    563.2;     553.9
```

program

```
awk '
BEGIN {
FS=";";
HITp=0;
HITn=0;
}
{
  arr1[NR] = $1;
  if($1=="P" && arr1[NR-1]!="N" && $4 < $2){HITp++}else{HITp=HITp}

  if($1=="N" && arr1[NR-1]!="P" && $4 > $3){HITn++}else{HITn=HITn}

  printf "%12s;%9.2f;%9.2f;%9d;%9d;%9.2f\n",$1,$2,$3,HITp,HITn,$4
}' input.txt >output
```

output

```
N;    577.5;    551.9;    0;    0;    0
P;    574.9;    556.9;    0;    0;    586.4
N;    561.95;   514.3;    0;    0;    504.01
P;    545;      520;      0;    0;    555.9
P;    559.05;   530.5;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    544.85;   522.25;   1;    0;    555.9
P;    543;      527;      1;    0;    555.9
P;    536.7;    517.7;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    540.55;   527.25;   1;    0;    555.9
P;    551.6;    525.2;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    542.1;    527;      1;    0;    555.9
P;    541;      521.2;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    541.9;    524.7;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    575.3;    532;      2;    0;    555.9
P;    572.8;    550;      3;    0;    555.9
P;    568.4;    541.45;   4;    0;    555.9
P;    574;      535;      5;    0;    555.9
P;    564;      548.4;    6;    0;    555.9
P;    572.05;   552.45;   7;    0;    555.9
P;    591.85;   565.15;   8;    0;    555.9
P;    602;      582.25;   9;    0;    555.9
P;    609;      575;     10;    0;    555.9
P;    611.95;   578.05;  11;    0;    555.9
P;    628;      604.9;   12;    0;    555.9
P;    611;      581;     13;    0;    555.9
N;    582.8;    565.2;   13;    0;    553.9
N;    581.5;    563.2;   13;    1;    553.9
```

but i want output look like this:

```
N;    577.5;    551.9;    0;    0;    0
P;    574.9;    556.9;    0;    0;    586.4
N;    561.95;   514.3;    0;    0;    504.01
P;    545;      520;      0;    0;    555.9
P;    559.05;   530.5;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    544.85;   522.25;   1;    0;    555.9
P;    543;      527;      1;    0;    555.9
P;    536.7;    517.7;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    540.55;   527.25;   1;    0;    555.9
P;    551.6;    525.2;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    542.1;    527;      1;    0;    555.9
P;    541;      521.2;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    541.9;    524.7;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    575.3;    532;      1;    0;    555.9
P;    572.8;    550;      1;    0;    555.9
P;    568.4;    541.45;   1;    0;    555.9
P;    574;      535;      1;    0;    555.9
P;    564;      548.4;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    572.05;   552.45;   1;    0;    555.9
P;    591.85;   565.15;   1;    0;    555.9
P;    602;      582.25;   1;    0;    555.9
P;    609;      575;      1;    0;    555.9
P;    611.95;   578.05;   1;    0;    555.9
P;    628;      604.9;    1;    0;    555.9
P;    611;      581;      1;    0;    555.9
N;    582.8;    565.2;    1;    0;    553.9
N;    581.5;    563.2;    1;    1;    553.9
```

Comment: awk '
    BEGIN {
    FS=";";
    HITp=0;
    HITn=0;
    }
    {
      arr1[NR] = $1;
       tig=0;
       tigs=0;
      if($1=="P" && arr1[NR-1]!="N" && $4<$2 && tig==0){HITp++;tig=1;}else{HITp=HITp}
      if($1=="N" && arr1[NR-1]!="P" && $4>$3 && tigs==0){HITn++;tigs=1;}else{HITn=HITn}

      printf "%12s;%9.2f;%9.2f;%9d;%9d;%9.2f\n",$1,$2,$3,HITp,HITn,$4
    }' input.txt >output

Comment: Perhaps change `{HITp++}` to `{HITp=1}`, and similarly for `HITn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       awk '
    BEGIN {
    FS=";";
    HITp=0;
    HITn=0;
    }
    {
      arr1[NR] = $1;
       tig=0;
       tigs=0;
      if($1=="P" && arr1[NR-1]!="N" && $4$3 && tigs==0){HITn++;tigs=1;}else{HITn=HITn}

      printf "%12s;%9.2f;%9.2f;%9d;%9d;%9.2f\n",$1,$2,$3,HITp,HITn,$4
    }' input.txt >output
```